# jQuery, search for element with value in attribute among the matched elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I find a collection of `a` tags using jQuery like this:

```
itemsPresent = $('h3.zn-ItemTitle > a');
```

Later in my scripts I need to find the `a` within the matched elements with a specific url in its `href` attribute without making a new jQuery select.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can call [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) on `itemsPresent` later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`attribute equals`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector:

```
itemsPresent = $('h3.zn-ItemTitle > a[href="http://your-url.com"]');
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep them as separate objects:

```
var itemsPresent = $('h3.zn-ItemTitle > a'),
    filteredAnchors = itemsPresent.filter('[href="http://your-url.com"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.filter()` to filter the Jquery object based on your desired conditions.

Try,

```
itemsPresent.filter(function(){   
  return $(this).attr('href') == 'something';
})
```

Or as BenM suggested you can use,

```
itemsPresent.filter('[href="something"]');
```

Comment: Why not just filter by the `attribute equals` selector?

Comment: @BenM I'm not 100% certain in this instance, but attribute selectors are usually incredibly slow compared to reading properties directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can **[filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** the collection

```
itemsPresent = $('h3.zn-ItemTitle > a');

var otherItems1 = itemsPresent.filter('[href="someUrl"]');

//or

var otherItems2 = itemsPresent.filter(function() {
    return this.href.indexOf('someURL') != -1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter`:

```
var $a = itemsPresent.filter(function() {
    return $(this).prop('href') == 'http://your-website.com';
});
```